# Update audit records using client credentials grant type

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server, clientcredential

I'm trying to set up Identity Server in a multi-tenancy environment but I'm struggling to get the ClientCredentials Grant Type and how I can audit record changes.

If I use the code flow grant type I obviously have a user & roles. I can then create an authorization policy based on the roles and the user. i.e. must be an authenticated user and have role "x".

As I have user data (and tenant data), I can then update my records with which user updated the record. e.g. Customer Bob was updated by user 999.

But how is this possible with an m2m account which I understand should use client credentials?

So Customer Bob is updated by the m2m account but who/what do I say updated the record? I understand that an m2m account doesn't have a user but something has still updated the customer record. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Use the concept of a service account. A service account updated your record

Comment: Ok... But let's say my customer table has an UpdatedBy column which is an int. That is a user id, if I use a process account it still needs an Id. How does the record know what updated it? Customer record Bob update by id 1, that could be a user or service account.

Comment: If you know who initiated the m2m call, you can send that information in using a custom header as well.